# COUNT (*) returns outdated number of rows after INSERT INTO or TRUNCATE

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, avro

I have a table with an avro schema where I insert tweets periodically.

```
CREATE TABLE tweets
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED as INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='hdfs:///tweet_schema.avsc');
```

When I run

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tweets;
```

I get only the count of the rows added by the last INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE tweets SELECT tweet FROM another_table;
```

Similarly, if I run

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tweets;
```

Querying for the count returns the table rows count before truncating, however, selecting everything returns nothing as expected.

Is this the expected behavior?

If it's indeed the expected behavior, what should I be doing to get the total number of rows?

I'm running Hive 0.13

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the expected behavior from `COUNT`. Are you by any chance doing an `OVERWRITE` in your `INSERT` statement?

Comment: @visakh no it doesn't overwrite, the data is there. If I run this statement `SELECT * FROM tweets;` I get all the rows expected, old and newly added but querying for the count returns only the number of the latest addition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned to be a bug, I reported it and got resolved in 0.14.0. You can watch the issue here [HIVE-7213](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7213)

A workaround is to:

```
set hive.compute.query.using.stats=false;
```